# Sitecore User Group June 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are super excited to announce the June'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

The lifecycle of goals and personalization in projects by Jill Grozalsky, Director of Digital Strategy at Brainjocks and Sitecore Strategy MVP

Practical IoT and Sitecore pairings with Cognigy.AI by Sandy Foley, Technical Lead Verndale and Sitecore Technologist MVP

Date & Time (EST):- Tuesday, June, 04, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Tuesday, June, 04, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/261460769/) for more details and RSVP.